# Android - Alter animation in resource file

Tags: android, animation, resources, translation

I have a transition from one activity to another that I am using in overridePendingTransition. Unfortunately all overridePendingTransition uses is the resource id of the file, so I am having trouble about how to edit this file so my transitions are proper.

Basically what I need to do is make changes to the R.anim.flip_in_scale_in so that I can change the value of the transitions fromX/toX so that it is set based on the user's screen size.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.flip_in_scale_in, R.anim.stationary_item);
```

How do I update the R.anim.flip_in_scale_in file before use in the overridePendingTransition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way you can alter the animation from the resource file in the way you want.

However, you CAN create the animation to use percentages rather than dp values.  When the animation is applied to the `Activity`'s View, it will animate entirely on the view's size (which in most cases is the screen size).

This for example:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500"
        />
</set>
```

Will slide in the view from the right side to the screen within half-a-second.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

This will increase the view to 40% it's current size over the span of one second.  The pivot will be directly in the middle of the view regardless of the view's size.

Comment: if you don't implicitly set the xDelta with a % at the end is it defaulted to px?

Comment: I have no idea what it's defaulted too.  I assume it's `dp`, but it's never safe to assume.  I know for a fact it's not percentage though.

Comment: alright thanks a lot, going to try this out on the different device sizes I have and see how it goes, will let you know!

Comment: Using percentages makes it more consistent across the devices. Thanks a lot